# Unable to install software--Getting error code 1

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, software-center, dpkg

I am unable to install any new software, and any apt-get command returns error code 1. In the Ubuntu Software Center, I get the error "New software can't be installed, because there is a problem with the software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?" And if I click repair, nothing happens. I am afraid that it is related to Codeblocks, which was recently installed. I have restarted numerous times, as other threads related to the same problem suggested, and I have followed many of their commands. It seemed to work for them, but it does nothing for me. Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

```
sudo apt-get -f install returns:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libbonoboui2-0 libbonoboui2-common libglade2-0 libgnomecanvas2-0
  libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-0 libgnomeui-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-dev gamin libcodeblocks0 libgamin0
  libwxsmithlib-dev
Recommended packages:
  valgrind
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  codeblocks-headers
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gamin libgamin0 libwxsmithlib-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-dev libcodeblocks0
3 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 to remove and 81 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 5,309 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,163 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe codeblocks-dev amd64                               13.12-3 [350 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libcodeblocks0 amd64 13.12-3 [1,807 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe gamin amd64 0.1.10-4.1ubuntu1 [41.1 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libgamin0 amd64 0.1.10-4.1ubuntu1 [16.4 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe codeblocks-contrib amd64 13.12-3 [3,018 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe libwxsmithlib-dev amd64 13.12-3 [75.1 kB]
Fetched 5,309 kB in 8s (643 kB/s)                                              
(Reading database ... 338385 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking codeblocks-dev (13.12-3) over (13.12-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-    3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/externaldepsdlg.h', which is also in     package codeblocks-headers 13.12-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by using Synaptics Package Manager (Hopefully anyone with this problem already had it installed, or I don't know what to say.) to remove any trace of Codeblocks. As much as I would like to use it, I'm afraid I will have to settle for something else, or keep looking for a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: A few months later, I tried installing Codeblocks through the Software Center, which I didn't before, and it works fine with everything now.

Answer (score 1):

First clean the programs which is causing the issue using the below command,

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get -f install

sudo apt-get update

After this try to install the software.

Comment: I posted the results of sudo apt-get -f install in my main post above. I don't know what to do. I have tried all of this stuff before that I read from other threads.

Comment: What can I do? This is really frustrating, I have some software that i really need to install. For now, I am using a different computer for it, but it would be much better if I could use this computer.